# css grow container and footer in bottom

Tags: html, css

**The CSS Code :**

```
 #container
    {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:450px;
    background-color:#ddd;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    
    
    #footer
    {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50%;
    background-color:#111;
    bottom:0px;
    }
    
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
```

Tis code from css, show simple container and the classic footer div, with this situation i can put always in the bottom the footer div, but i have the next questions and problems.

1 ) When the container grows, even though the footer is at the bottom, the container exceeds it

2 ) What I'm looking for is that if the container grows, the footer always stays below or below, I'm not looking to use fixed position

3 ) At the same time if the container doesn't grow, the footer is always on the bottom, but if the container grows, it stays below

I try all, modificate body and use position relative inside, but i can´t get this results i need, because the content inside container change of size.

Thank´s for the help, best regards.

Comment: Have you tried putting the footer inside the container? https://jsfiddle.net/vy8qae61/

Comment: If i put inside container always grow inside container and i want show in the bottom always in the bottom of screen, because if y put inside container, always in the bottom there are space if the container not have many height

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2L5ctyeb/

Comment: The solution that I thought of is nearly identical to Michael's second jsfiddle so I won't post it as an answer. Use flexbox and `justify-content: space-between` to position the footer at the bottom of the viewport when the content and footer do not fill the viewport. The only difference I would make is to use `min-height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100vh`